# Another Stubborn Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, analysis

ReBonjour.
Let $x$ and $y$ be two real numbers. Show that $ \frac{ |x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\leq\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac {|y|}{1+|y|}$
Thanks a lot.

Comment: If both $x$ and $y$ are zero, then this is false. I think you mean $\frac{ |x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\leq\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac {|y|}{1+|y|}$

Comment: Corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x}
$$
is increasing (by taking derivatives or simply by using the fact that $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}\iff ad<bc$) whence
$$
|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|
$$
implies that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\leq\frac{|x|+|y|}{1+|x|+|y|}&=\frac{|x|}{1+|x|+|y|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|x|+|y|}\\&\leq
\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+
\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}
\end{align}
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $$1-\frac{1}{1+|x+y|}\leq 1-\frac{1}{1+|x|}$$ $$1-\frac{1}{1+|x+y|}\leq 1-\frac{1}{1+|y|}$$

So $$2-\frac{2}{1+|x+y|}\leq 1-\frac{1}{1+|x|}+1-\frac{1}{1+|y|}$$

Thus $$\frac{2|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\leq \frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}$$

$$\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}< \frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}$$

Comment: If $x=y=0$, strict inequality does not occur.

Comment: Angelo $x$ is not supposed to be positive. Your argument does not hold.